# Can't find data_warehouse ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, data-warehouse

I am working on a project and i was trying make it up and running in my local machine. But unfortunately the app is using a gem data_warehouse( found gem 'data_warehouse', '= 1.5.2' in environment.rb), I tried to look for this gem but can't find this gem, I was unable to run the application because of this. I never used data warehousing in ruby on rails either. I am slightly aware of the concept data warehousing. If any one aware of this gem please post the url for this gem or an alternate solution for avoiding this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither can I. Now, assuming that you have a production machine where this gem is found:

You can see the installed gems with:

```
gem list
```

Go to production machine and run

```
gem env
```

There, you should see something like

> - REMOTE SOURCES:
>
>   - http://gems.rubyforge.org/
>   - http://gems.github.com/

After running the same command on your local computer, you can add the missing remote sources with:

```
sudo gem sources -a "http://missing_remote_sources"
```

and then try to install your gem.

If this doesn't work, you could also try a monkey-patch. Run

```
rake gems:unpack
```

on your production server. After this, you will be able to find your gem in the /vendor/gems folder. Copy the folder into your local vendor folder and it should work.

Btw, as it could just be a typo: have you tried commenting the line in the config file?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I also thought about vendorizing the gems, anyway we asked the client mail the zip of the gem that they have in production.

Comment: You're welcome :). If the response helped you, you can mark it as 'Helpful' (one vote up, from the up/down arrows). If the response answered your question, you can mark it as 'Accepted' (the green checkmark).